# IAR Compiler: using struct with function pointers, map file shows all the function declared in struct irrespective of function used or not

Tags: c, pointers, dictionary, struct, iar

I have a struct with 10 function pointers. A global instance of the struct is initialized wit function pointers pointing to local functions. 
In my application, using any one or more of the function references causes linker to include all 10 functions in the map file.

In order to save memory, I need linker to include onle those functions that used in the application. Not all the functions referenced in the struct.

**Struct in file r_adc_api.h** (from Manufacturer)

```
typedef struct st_adc_api
    {
        ssp_err_t (* open)(adc_ctrl_t * const p_ctrl,  adc_cfg_t const * const      p_cfg);
        ssp_err_t (* scanCfg)(adc_ctrl_t * const p_ctrl,  adc_channel_cfg_t const * const p_channel_cfg);
        ssp_err_t (* scanStart)(adc_ctrl_t * const p_ctrl);
        ssp_err_t (* scanStop)(adc_ctrl_t * const p_ctrl);
        ssp_err_t (* scanStatusGet)(adc_ctrl_t * const p_ctrl);
        ssp_err_t (* read)(adc_ctrl_t  * const p_ctrl, adc_register_t const  reg_id,  adc_data_size_t * const p_data);
        ssp_err_t (* sampleStateCountSet)(adc_ctrl_t * const p_ctrl,  adc_sample_state_t  * p_sample);
        ssp_err_t (* close)(adc_ctrl_t * const p_ctrl);
        ssp_err_t (* infoGet) (adc_ctrl_t * const p_ctrl, adc_info_t * const p_adc_info);
        ssp_err_t (* versionGet)(ssp_version_t * const p_version);
    } adc_api_t;
```

**Header r_adc.h ** (from Manufacturer)

```
extern const adc_api_t g_adc_on_adc;
```

**Assignment and function definitions is in file r_adc.c** (from Manufacturer)

```
const adc_api_t g_adc_on_adc =
{
    .open                   = R_ADC_Open,
    .scanCfg                = R_ADC_ScanConfigure,
    .infoGet                = R_ADC_InfoGet,
    .scanStart              = R_ADC_ScanStart,
    .scanStop               = R_ADC_ScanStop,
    .scanStatusGet          = R_ADC_CheckScanDone,
    .sampleStateCountSet    = R_ADC_SetSampleStateCount,
    .read                   = R_ADC_Read,
    .close                  = R_ADC_Close,
    .versionGet             = R_ADC_VersionGet
};
```

and ## Function Definitions ##

** MAP File **
[MAP file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2bDa.jpg)

In my Application, if i use adc_on_g_adc.open(...); linker pulls all 10 symbols to the map file instead of just pulling **R_ADC_Open();**

What might be causing .map file to pull all the functions from the struct even if one function is called?

**Edit:** Putting all these together in one single file gives map file I need. IAR compiler omits unused functions. Just doesn't work when I use multiple header and source.

Comment: First of all each static assignment in the ***.h** file will be copied as many times as you used it in different cases. Second, it's not clear what you would like to achieve? Dynamic size of the callback structure? It's semi-possible if you have a list of functions where you register function at runtime. That's how plugins are being registered usually.

Comment: 0andriy, thanks for the reply. This is given from the manufacturer and I am supposed to use it with some alteration. Their Idea of doing this is, use Interface (function pointers) without much worrying about whats happening in the function call. I am playing around inside of it because of the code section optimization.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Reduce amount of words and give just simple example: a) what is exists and b) what you would like to achieve.

Comment: 0andriy, adc_on_g_adc is an interface for my application which gives me access to ADC module. Eg. I use one these function as adc_on_g_adc.open() in my application. Now, If I use one or more functions from the struct, MAP file shows all the function symbols instead of showing symbols for the function used.   Just ignore the Static code, I was experimenting there.

Comment: Update the post, please. There is an article how to ask good question.

Comment: Updated! Hope its clear now.

Comment: The answer is quite simple to your question. The compiler doesn't know what functions are going to be used. It includes all of them! There are some tricks to avoid this, but in your case the simplest choice (if you have sources of the library you are using) is just cut the functions from the library.  **But** looking into API I hardly can imagine how you use only **one** function from it. it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @0andriy, Thanks for the answer, it makes sense. However, its manual to go end edit the code. Thats not something I am looking for. I want compiler to sense this. If I put all this code in one single file that has main(), the compiler senses it correctly and omits unused ones. Also, I am just taking use of one function as an example, I ll definitely need more.

Comment: Yeah, you need some linker tricks. I dunno if LTO helps here, otherwise I doubt that exported variant of functions can be eliminated easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fill up the structure with function pointers, the functions have been "used" so far as the linker is concerned.

Think about it in terms of what the linker is supposed to replace `R_ADC_ScanConfigure` with. It can't choose to set `g_adc_on_adc.scanCfg` to NULL, can it? It doesn't know that the object code doesn't actually call `g_adc_on_adc.scanCfg`.

Basically, it's only option is to include `R_ADC_ScanConfigure` in the output.

However, if instead of assigning `R_ADC_ScanConfigure` in the structure *you* set `g_adc_on_adc.scanCfg` to NULL, the linker would then be able omit `R_ADC_ScanConfigure` from the output.

```
const adc_api_t g_adc_on_adc =
{
    .open                   = R_ADC_Open,
    .scanCfg                = NULL,
    .infoGet                = R_ADC_InfoGet,
    .scanStart              = R_ADC_ScanStart,
    .scanStop               = R_ADC_ScanStop,
    .scanStatusGet          = R_ADC_CheckScanDone,
    .sampleStateCountSet    = R_ADC_SetSampleStateCount,
    .read                   = R_ADC_Read,
    .close                  = R_ADC_Close,
    .versionGet             = R_ADC_VersionGet
};
```

Of course, if your code then did end up calling `g_adc_on_adc.scanCfg` you'd be trying to run code at address 0 (probably), which would be a very bad thing indeed. You could make `.scanCfg` point to a function that simply prints up a nasty error message on your console / down your serial port / whatever so that at least you know something has gone wrong.

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to answer. Pls check my edit in the question. All these code together in one file gives me linker-output I need. Meaning, if I use one function, MAP file has only that function. It just doesn't work with code scattered in multiple header and source files. In my opinion, its a matter of using right scope or linking option or something I do not know. In any case, I definitely do not want to play with function reference as you are suggesting. There has to be a way for linker to know about unused functions in scattered code as its the case of code in one file

Comment: Putting everything together in one file allows the compiler to recognise that parts of the `g_adc_on_adc` structure are entirely unused, and can optimise them away. Bit like declaring variables that are unused - the compiler simply does away with them altogether.

Comment: However, I'm afraid there is no linking option to do what you want. If you declare `g_adc_on_adc` with every field assigned to a function and the compiler doesn't have the opportunity to optimise unused fields away because you have multiple source code files, then the linker has no choice but to include the referenced functions in the resulting executable.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is called virtual function elimination and does just what you want but for only for virtual functions in C++.

In your code all the compiler sees is a structure initialized with some pointers to functions. If this structure is global or somehow exported from this module the compiler must assume that all the initialized parts of the structure are used.

When the linker gets hold of all this it sees a reference to the structure, that's all. There is no information there to tell the linker what part of the structure is used.

When you put everything in the same module the compiler can find out what function you actually reference and go there directly, this will leave the structure without references meaning it can be thrown away and with it all the references to the other functions.